# Where is the file contains log for last command (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The **last** command shows us which users have been logged in but how can I find the file that the command  **last** does read and process it ?

Comment: Did you read the manual page (`man last`) - in particular the `FILES` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which files are opened by a given program with strace like that:

```
$ strace last |& grep open
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/var/log/wtmp", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

The file you're looking for is `/var/log/wtmp`.  You can read more about it in `man 5 wtmp`.

Comment: A simpler route for the non-programer is to read [the FILES section of the manual](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/util-linux/last.1.en.html#FILES) and then follow the cross-reference in [the SEE ALSO section](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/util-linux/last.1.en.html#SEE_ALSO).

Comment: @JdeBP: It's not necessarily *simpler* to scan manpages that in addition may be outdated or may not be available at all on Busybox based system for example (although OP added [tag:Ubuntu] here). And it's very possible that OP is a programmer because they said they want to *process* the file they're asking about which indicates some automatic procedure.

Comment: Answers are not for just one person.